# How to center tab text vertically

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I customized tab layout for tab activity in my Android app. The problem is how to center it vertically. The text is centered horizontally automatically. I tried writing `gravity:center`, `layout_gravity:center`. Even more: I tried writing exact height in my `TextView`, but nothing works (actually exact pixels work great, but when I change device orientation - text is not centrally oriented.

That's my code for tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_name"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's screenshot of my problem:
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot-2]

Comment: I m not exactly sure what is going wrong. Could you post some images that could help. Also what would be the height and width of the textview in dp?

Comment: What do you want to center vertically the text or the widget?

Comment: @ngoa I updated the post with link on picture with my problem

Comment: @StepanMazokha Did u try using actionBar and see it that works? just a suggestion!

Comment: @ngoa what do you mean by saying "using actionBar"? By the way, I am adding the tabs programmatically in this way: mCustomView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
                    textView = (TextView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.tab_name);
                    textView.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));                 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(mCustomView).setTabListener(mActivity));

Comment: @StepanMazokha I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong since I need my workstation to debug this. But you try activating "Show Layout Boundaries" from the developer options to see how the layout is affected.

Comment: @ngoa layout is not affected at all. there is no difference before and after applying gravity attributes. I could add paddings programmatically, but I need to have tab height - can't find the way how to get it. (using action bar height is not appropriate because tab height and actionbar height are different on multiple screens)

Comment: @StepanMazokha Very weird... I might get to work on this immediately but when I get time, I will test this manually and see what might be going wrong.

Comment: @ngoa ok, thank you. will be waiting for your response

Comment: @ngoa Actually the thing that helped me is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22144844/3649567

Comment: @StepanMazokha Sorry I never got back to you. Totally forgot to open my workstation over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `android:gravity="center"` to the `LinearLayout` and
use `wrap_content` for `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.. I updated my post with link to the screenshot with my problem (code, you've given in your answer is applied there)

Comment: Please enable `Show layout bounds` in developer options and post an additional screenshot :)

Comment: I've added screenshot to the post

Comment: Looks like there is some `padding`. Maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23241518/4193263

Comment: thank you for your help, but the thing that helped me was written here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22144844/3649567